# Performing COST PATH in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, cost-path

I have a tiff raster dataset serving as cost raster, created a start point and destination point serving as feature source data for performing **COST PATH in ArcMap 10.4.**

Since the tiff raster layer contains no attribute table, I performed INT to get one. However, this new-made attribute table does not contain the value for each pixel.

I have also performed RASTER to POINT to get the value of each pixel. But I cannot join this table to INT attribute table.  I am wondering if this is the reason I failed to get a normal result of COST DISTANCE  and COST BACKLINK.

Besides, I have already tried performing PATHWAY in IDRISI. But it failed too.

Answer (score 0):

Preformed a LCP before using this YouTube video and model builder I highly suggest checking it out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3q0DpV8NQo

Comment: When I run the model, error 999999, error010045 and error010067 comes up. Pls refer to the new-added image above.

Answer (score 0):

I found this youtube video to be really helpful. Follow the steps and it should work with your files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0Eywj4pIu8

Comment: Thank you @Racheal. The above result is what I got after I watched this video.

Comment: Thx Mandy. Are you start and finish points two separate files with no other points inside?

Comment: Also, you should not need attribute table - the raster values serve as the cost just fine.

Comment: Yes, the start point and finish point are two separate file with just one point respectively.